# Centralizing task scheduler

Tags: java, smartfoxserver

We are using a task scheduler in our smartfox extension and we have 6 different schedule tasks. With each extension request, smartfox' active thread count increase by the number of threadpool size we set for each scheduleexecutor service. Looks like we need to get 1 scheduler centralized and reference to from other classes. We just dont know how to keep a reference to it and create a new task without populating active thread pool with new threads.
Please let me know how to centralize the scheduler and keep reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the scheduleexecutors with a [Quartz scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) - you can set the maximum number of threads in its threadpool via the `org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount` config property.

The easiest way to make a reference to the scheduler available in all of your threads, e.g.

```
public class SchedulerWrapper {
    private static Scheduler scheduler;

    public static void addJob(JobDetail jobDetail) {
        scheduler.addJob(jobDetail, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this cause any slowing-down during the game? It is a multiplayer poker game btw. thanks

Comment: It shouldn't cause any slowing down so long as you set the threadpool to an appropriate size, e.g. one thread per player plus one thread for the dealer.